# How can I remove an uncessessary extended partition with only one member in gparted?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, logical-drive

I've been changing this hard drive around, and have stumbled into this problem. I'm trying to get my hard drive back to just its original 4 partitions, but I can't seem to get rid of the "shell" of an extended partition. Right now, it's structure like:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3 (EXTENDED)
    /dev/sda5 (logical)
/dev/sda4
```

I would like to "pull out" /dev/sda5 and replace /dev/sda3 entirely with it. from the extended partition and get rid of it entirely.

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3 (formerly /dev/sda5)
/dev/sda4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: /dev/sda3 is the group partition containing the /dev/sda5 extended partition. So, you already have just 4 partitions: sda1, 2, 5 & 4. Ignore sda3 as the group or container. I'm not sure what are you trying to get rid of ?

Comment: Are there any consequences to having this unnecessary container? I'm trying to make it so it has only 4 primary partitions, the extended partition doesn't need to be there.

Comment: There are no "consequences" to having a container. It is a natural side effect of having an extended/logical partition within a primary one. Also, extended partition has no feature restrictions compared to primary, its only to facilitate your having more than 4 overall number of partitions. In short, you don't need to worry about it!

Answer (score 0):

Use **gparted** utility to first delete

```
/dev/sda5
```

and the deleting

```
/dev/sda3
```

and here you will get rid of extended partition, the it should be

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
 free space
/dev/sda4
```

now create new **primary** partition with your choice of file system. thats it its done.